# SUMIF by both date and category?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to summarize a list of expenses by both which month they were dated, and what category of expense they were. I know that this is a job for SUMIF, but I've tried to make this work in multiple ways and it's just not coming out correctly.

My current best guess has been to put in each of the individual result cells:
=SUMIF($A$4:$C$14, AND($E5, MONTH()=F$4),$C$4:$C$14)

I know this doesn't work, especially since I'm leaving the MONTH() function blank, but I don't know how to tell Excel that i'm looking for the month value of the expense's corresponding date.

I've been struggling with this - any advice is greatly appreciated!!

[image: Data and desired result]

Comment: A pivot table should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Pivot table.

Put The date in Columns but only keep the months.

Put the Category in the rows and the Amount in values making sure it is set to sum:

[image]

---

If you really want a formula then bracket the dates using EOMONTH:

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,">" & EOMONTH(DATE(2018,F$4,1),-1),$A:$A,"<=" & EOMONTH(DATE(2018,F$4,1),0),$B:$B,$E5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although a pivot table is my preference, if you really just want a formula, then this requires `SUMIFS` not `SUMIF`.

`SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range_1, criteria_1, [criteria_range_2, criteria_2, ... criteria_range_n, criteria_n])`   *{n<=127}*

I can't think of a way to do the Month() comparison within the `SUMIFS` statement, but you could insert a helper column.  (For this example, I've assumed the use of column D and not an inserted column so that the remaining columns keep the same letter.)

In cell D4, put `=MONTH(A4)`, then drag that formula down.

If you want to sum column C values if both column B and A values match a criteria, then based on your cell references you have and the use of the helper column, this would be the equivalent of what you were trying to do in the `SUMIF` statement:

`=SUMIFS($C$4:$C$14, $B$4:$B$14, $E5, $D$4:$D$14, F$4)`